# How to get keyword from html template - Django

Tags: python, django, search

I am starting to learn Django and I defined class based views, I created a view that you can manually input books details like: title, author, ... I also added search box in that same view that should find automatically book details by api's and web scraping. Results should be display on new view, new url that changes based on users input, with multiple results that user would select best fit.

Problem is that, I don't know yet how to receive users input from defined search box and pass it to another view (different class) that will manipulate it.

Search box in template:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <form id="custom-search-input" action="{% url 'find_book' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div class="input-group col-sm-10" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Find books" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Defined class where user can input:

```
class BookCreateView (CreateView, SuccessMessageMixin,):
    model = Appointment
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'time']
    success_message = 'Appointment successfully created.'

    def get_context(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(BookCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Class that I want results to show (have no idea how):

```
class BookFindView (View):
    response_template = 'book_find.html'
```

Any hint or tutorial or documentation advised would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is this a question on how Django Views can accept user input?
With simpler views, [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21207496/1842146) should do the job (and I also think using a `def` instead of a `class` for these simpler views, like BookFindView is more likely to be a better option).

Answer (score 1):

Any view can implement both "get" and "post" handling; that way you can have something like

```
class BookCreateView(views.View):
    # subclass the basic form and add an hidden input named search
    form = your_custom_search_form
    # subclass the create model form
    confirmation_form = your_custom_create_model_form

def get(request):
    # show the empty search page
    # in your template use the form to implement search

def post(request):
    # handle the book search; there is a data in the payload named search
    # you now have a payload to use; here you make a database query 
    # and return the similar books; every book is printed in the page
    # using the your_custom_create_model_form that you can prepopulate

    # handle the confirmation of the book otherwise; the post
    # payload will contain the book information
```